# glDrawArrays(...) won't draw anything

Tags: c++, opengl

I have problems to draw something using glDrawArrays() and no other question here could help me solve it. The code should draw a sphere, but for debuging I fill "m_vertices" with the vertices for a simple cube. 
My Code is following:

First the init function.

```
init()
{
m_shader.compileShaders("Shaders/colorShading.vert", "Shaders/colorShading.frag");
m_shader.addAttribute("position");
m_shader.addAttribute("normal");
m_shader.linkShaders();

//setup VAO and VBO
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);

//init VAO
glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
//bind Buffer used by VAO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
//enable needed AttributeArrays
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
//position attribute pointer
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexBuffer), (void*)offsetof(VertexBuffer, vertex));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(VertexBuffer), (void*)offsetof(VertexBuffer, normal));
//release VAO
glBindVertexArray(0);
//release VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

//Set-Up a static scene
// Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
// Camera matrix
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(4, 3, 3), // Camera is at (4,3,3), in World Space
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), // and looks at the origin
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );
// Model Matrix
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
//set ModelViewProjection-Matrix of this object
m_mvp = projection * view * model;
}
```

This function is used to set up everything needed to draw my Object. 
Then there is an update function:

```
update()
{
//update Sphere and get current vertices
//currently setting vertices for a cube
m_sphere->updateSphere(m_vertices);

//m_vertices is passed in per reference
//it stores 6 quads based on 2 triangles (36 vertices)
//the vertices are stored counter clockwise

//update VBO
//bind buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
//orphan the buffer
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertices.size() * sizeof(VertexBuffer), nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//upload data
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, m_vertices.size() * sizeof(VertexBuffer), &m_vertices[0]);
//release buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

The update function updates the VBO. This is needed cause the final Sphere should implement LevelOfDetail.
And finally the draw function:

```
draw()
{
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//activate shader
m_shader.use();

//set-up the mvp-uniform
GLuint matrixID = m_shader.getUniformLocation("MVP");
glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &m_mvp[0][0]);

//draw Planet
glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_vertices.size());
glBindVertexArray(0);

//deactivate shader
m_shader.unuse();

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

This function should just binds/sets up the shader and draw the object. 
The problem is that it doesn't draw the object and I have no idea why.
If someone could spot my mistake and explain what I did wrong here, I would be very grateful.

EDIT:

So as requested I add my code, which fills in the cube data:

```
static const std::vector<GLfloat> g_vertex_buffer_data = {
-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
};

updateSphere(std::vector<VertexBuffer> &vertices)
{
if(!vertices.empty())
    vertices.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < g_vertex_buffer_data.size();)
{
    VertexBuffer buffer;
    glm::vec3 vertex(g_vertex_buffer_data[i], g_vertex_buffer_data[i+1], g_vertex_buffer_data[i+2]);
    buffer.setVertex(vertex);
    buffer.setNormal(glm::normalize(vertex));
    vertices.emplace_back(buffer);
    i += 3;
}
}
```

Also the VertexBuffer struct:

```
struct Vector3 {
float x;
float y;
float z;
};

struct VertexBuffer {
Vector3 vertex;
Vector3 normal;

void setVertex(glm::vec3 vec)
{
    vertex.x = vec.x;
    vertex.y = vec.y;
    vertex.z = vec.z;
}
void setNormal(glm::vec3 vec)
{
    normal.x = vec.x;
    normal.y = vec.y;
    normal.z = vec.z;
}
};
```

My shader class is already tested in serveral other projects and works perfectly fine. I assume that I missmanage the VAO and VBO or the cube data. But I could be completly wrong here.

And I corrected the VAO generation, that was my bad and I wonder why I didn't see this. But that didn't fix the problem here.

The color and depth buffer get cleared in the mainloop of my project. Should I clear them on every draw call of an Object?

Comment: I see this was voted to close as not minimal, verifiable and complete. Would the voter care to specify what's missing? In terms of minimalism, I'd say this is actually quite small for an `opengl` snippet.

Comment: I agree 100%. However, the shader and cube initialization are IMO missing (it could have some impact on the result).

Comment: You're using a depth test, do you ever clear your buffers? I don't see any code to do that in your snippets. Not clearing it can prevent it from passing any depth tests. Also, it would be good to see how you initialize your vertices. A lot of graphics problems usually spawn from improper initialization of systems.

Comment: Try error checking with `glGetError()`. I stopped reading at line 5, where you call `glGenBuffers()` to create a VAO. That needs to be `glGenVertexArrays()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I solved my problem. The code works perfectly fine, but for some reasons I messed up alpha values in my fragment shader. I haven't expected an error there cause i never used this testshader under active alphablending. And an additional thanks to @RetoKoradi for pointing out my VAO mistake.